# Density of granulated cane sugar

Tags: density

What is the density in `g/cm3` of cane sugar, for example in the following product: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01LYMXK56](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01LYMXK56) ?

Comment: You can google for the density of various materials; is that what you're looking for? Or are you asking how sugar crystals pack together?

Comment: I am producing a home made infused liquor, and online I seem to find many different values as to what the density of granulated cane sugar is. This is going to be essential in order to convert the grams of sugar into ml in order to have the correct ratio of sugar/water.

Comment: First of all, this isn't really a physics question — more like food science or chemistry. Second, I suspect there is not one standard answer, because it will depend on the size and shape of crystals from different manufacturers. I know there is a pretty big difference in the salt content of Diamond and Morton kosher salt because the crystals are different sizes, for example. Third, and most important: just buy a food scale.

Comment: Sorry, but a scale measures mass, how is that going to help me identify the volume of that mass?

Comment: You can also buy a 5 lb bag of sugar and measure it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mix a weighed amount of the sugar that you are going to use with a measured volume of water, when the sugar is dissolved into the water measure the volume of the mixture. The increase in volume will be the volume of the weight of sugar added.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, your question is really "How do I measure out $x$ grams of sugar when I only have volume measures"?

There are baking conversion charts online that give you rough estimates (google "grams of sugar per cup"), but you're never going to be very precise with that method, because sugar can be packed more or less densely in a container, depending on a lot of factors. If you're doing homebrewing or liquor making where you want repeatable measurements, you really want to pick up a $20 kitchen scale on Amazon. (With granulated sugar you might get by with a cup measure, but when it comes to herbs there's just no chance unless you have a scale.)